# Player score update with PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a users table where I want to update the scores each time a user finishes the game. Unityscript part is working fine but after I post the score to the database it appears doubled or tripled. I post the score as int and also the table column is of int format. My PHP looks like this:

```
try {

   $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $db_user, $db_pass);
   $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

   $data = array(
       ':username' => $_POST['username'],
       ':score' => $_POST['score']);

   $statement = $db -> prepare ("UPDATE users SET score = score + :score
                                 WHERE username = :username"); 
   $statement->execute($data);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: If you use prepared statements, use them all the way trough, also for $score..

Comment: What are you hardcoding `$score` into your query. You just circumvented your dql injection protection.

Comment: so much for prepared statements :D

Comment: You started doing the right thing by using prepared statemetns and then shot it.

Comment: I was using prepared statement first but it doesn't make any difference regarding to my problem.

Comment: Is there any other, surrounding code to go along?

Answer (score 0):

You are using prepared statements, but you are still allowing injection by directly implementing the `$score` variable. Do the same thing with score that you did with username.

What do you mean by double or triple? Do you mean that the number is two or three times bigger? If so, try using a `SELECT` statement to fetch the score and do the math in PHP. Then, `UPDATE` the `users` table.

Doing this will allow you to better understand what you are doing wrong. Have you tried echoing the value of `score` within your try and catch to see if the value repeats? The code may be running more than once.

Comment: Please do not use answers for comments and questions.

Comment: @JayBlanchard His question was confusing, so I answered what I thought his question was, while at the same time asking him to confirm. My apologies.

Comment: Yes that's right. If for example the old score was 100 and new score is 50 it makes it 250 instead of 150.

Comment: @yellowbedsheet Try doing as I suggested and `echo $score` inside the `try` statement. See if a) it is displayed three times or b) the value is just flat out incorrect.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @msrd0 - This looks like more than just a comment seeking clarification to me. It looks like an answer that will possibly be edited based on comments made on the answer, if the question wasn't clear enough so the answer isn't quite what was being looked for. Marking this as Looks Okay.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare But I see questions to the OP in the answer that should be comments. But I agree that that's not the only content of the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$statement = $db -> prepare ("UPDATE users SET score = :score
                             WHERE username = :username");
```

use this, i think it will work